# Encoding problems in PyQt

Tags: python, encoding, pyqt

My program stores file index in file packed by cPickle. There are non-english filenames.
When I just do this

```
print f [0]
```

where f [0] is "\xc2\xe8\xf1\xee\xea\xee\xf1\xed\xfb\xe9 \xe3\xee\xe4" ("Високосный год" in normal view), it prints the string in proper way — in russian.

When the program manually adds the string u'Високосный год' to QTreeView, everything is fine.

But when the program puts this string ("\xe3\xee\xe4" etc.) straight from unpickled file to QTreeView, it becomes like that:

[alt text http://img170.imageshack.us/img170/9226/encoding.png](http://img170.imageshack.us/img170/9226/encoding.png)

Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: I added a comment to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run `decode` on the unpickled string using the correct encoding ("cp1251" by the look of it)? If not, you need to do this to make sure you're passing a Unicode string to the GUI.

Comment: when i'm trying to decode string with cp1251, ascii or any other encoding, i'm getting error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: Don't use ASCII, as your string plainly contains non-ASCII characters. Use for example "\xe3\xee\xe4".decode("cp1251") which should result in "год" being displayed.

You can't use random encodings - it has to be the correct one which converts the bytes "\xe3\xee\xe4" to Unicode "год".